# Unable to locate package drush

Tags: composer-php, drush

hello everyone i am trying to install drush on my local system Ubuntu , but i get this error every time

> E: "Unable to locate package drush"

can anyone help me please to solve this problem

Comment: How do you install it? What versions of Drush and Drupal are you using? Starting with Drush 8.4 it only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal site be built with Composer and Drush be listed as a dependency. Also check the [compatibility chart](https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#drupal-compatibility).

Comment: i install it with composer , it is 8.* ' composer global require drush/drush:8.*'

Comment: See? That's not the preferred way. But nonetheless did you include your global Composer's bin dir to your PATH?

Comment: no not yet , i will do it now thanx bro